# Use PHP to get value from XML

Tags: php, xml

Still a little foggy here.  I need to get the value of an element in my xml file.  I am converting my website into a multilingual site and will use xml for the language files, kinda the same as I do with java and android.

My language xml file is located at  /path/en.xml

Some data located in the file is as follows:

```
<resources>
   <item id="sidebar">
        <link1>Dashboard</link1>
        <link2>Logs</link2>
        <link3>Forms</link3>
        <link4>Gallery</link4>
   </item>
   <item id="index.php">
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <value>VALUE</value>
        <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </item>
   <item id="config.php">
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <value>VALUE</value>
        <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </item>
</resources>
```

Now how do I get the DESCRIPTION value located at `item id="config.php"` in the third element?

UPDATE:  Ok for now in my header.php I am using:

```
<?php
    $valuelanguage = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='language'");
    $lang = mysql_result($valuelanguage, 0);
    $xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("xml/lang/{$lang}.xml");
    ?>
```

which is successfully loading my xml file.  Then in the file.php I want to get the "description" element for the item index.php.

```
example:    echo $xmldoc->item->attributes()->id['config.php']->description;
```

now all I need is the one liner that calls that value of that element.  I am close with the above but I can not get it any further???

Comment: Is there noone that knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use `xpath()` to select the `description` of the `item` with `id = 'config.php'`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // XML in $x
$description = (string)$xml->xpath("/resources/item[@id='config.php']/description")[0];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/216915